# Why Grid Search is not performed for Naive Bayes Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was looking at sklearn gridsearchcv but i see no gridsearch for GaussianNB. I am very beginner in this field.

Edit: Gaussian Naive Bayes may not have any hyperparameters but I know Bernoulli Naive Bayes has the hyperparameter of alpha. Can we potentially do grid search with this?

Comment: Why should it be used and what for?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a hyper-parameter to tune, so you have nothing to grid search over.

Comment: Argument "prior" is present. It tells the Prior probabilities of the classes. If specified the priors are not adjusted according to the data.

Comment: Just a thought, I've used NB almost exclusively for NLP tasks. Consider sentiment analysis, the distribution over the word "fast" might be `{pos:0.8, neg:0.2}`. this design is often called "unigram" (just one word), however, n-grams (2 or more) will improve accuracy. In general, perplexity is used to evaluate if added model complexity is worth the effort. All that to say, grid search might be useful, if you were trying to optimize the number of n-grams (though this would no longer be "Naive Bayes" but rather a conceptual extension.) But outside of NLP, there might be no use for this idea.